# Win32 small stack size strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 64bit, 4k pages and 64k allocation, I am unable to set less than 256kb for reserved stack size using VS2019 and a simple console application. If I specify 128k, vmmap will show at least 256kb reserved for the stack. Dumpbin print the correct values I set in project settings > Linker > system > reserved/committes size. Not sure what/where force the stack to have at least 256kb min, is it normal behavior? The program I am running is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler and linker settings are default from console application wizard. The program is compiled 64bit.

Comment: Off topic as C++, since this is windows specific (I assume, due to winapi tag)   i.e. not standard C++.     Would also be better if you provide relevant code, and info about your host system.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the code, it's a simple hello world program, I just change the stack size in VS linker settings.

Comment: Whether its a "hello world" program or a control system for a nuclear power plant, it's not like other people can guess what your code (or any other settings, such as those related to how you build it) does unless you provide that information.    It's a pretty unusual "hello world" program that is explicitly tweaked in a way that affects what memory it reserves.

Comment: Posting code (and the command line to compile and link) allows us to easily reproduce the issue, even when the issue isn't related to the code. And since you don't know what the issue is, you cannot preclude the code being part of it.

Comment: Used to be 64KB, but I noticed 256KB quite a while ago, Win7 iirc.  I *think* it is related to running on the 64-bit version of Windows.  In which case a thread of a 32-bit process has 3 stacks, one extra beyond the kernel stack (24KB) and the regular stack, there is also a stack used by the Wow64 emulator.  Whose minimum size is 256KB, as mentioned in Mark Russinovich' [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/ba-p/723824).

Comment: Why do you care about this? This is just reserved memory in the virtual address space - as long as your program doesn't use it, it won't do any harm at all.

Comment: @pmf Reserved memory, even when it's not being used, is no longer available. If you care about all the address space you can use, then this matters.

Comment: No, each process has its own address space. The size of the (virtual) memory available for each application is independent of how many applications run. If you're going to start thousands of processes, the limits will come from a different place (i.e. exhausted physical memory)